# pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, speech-recognition

This script will work on a 30 second wav file but not a 10 minutes phone call also in wav format. Any help would be appreciated

I've downloaded ffmpeg.

```
# Import necessary libraries 
from pydub import AudioSegment 
import speech_recognition as sr 
import os
import pydub


chunk_count = 0
directory = os.fsencode(r'C:\Users\zach.blair\Downloads\speechRecognition\New folder')
# Text file to write the recognized audio 
fh = open("recognized.txt", "w+")
for file in os.listdir(directory):
     filename = os.fsdecode(file)
     if filename.endswith(".wav"):
        chunk_count += 1
             # Input audio file to be sliced 
        audio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename,format="wav") 

        ''' 
        Step #1 - Slicing the audio file into smaller chunks. 
        '''
        # Length of the audiofile in milliseconds 
        n = len(audio) 

        # Variable to count the number of sliced chunks 
        counter = 1



        # Interval length at which to slice the audio file. 
        interval = 20 * 1000

        # Length of audio to overlap.  
        overlap = 1 * 1000

        # Initialize start and end seconds to 0 
        start = 0
        end = 0

        # Flag to keep track of end of file. 
        # When audio reaches its end, flag is set to 1 and we break 
        flag = 0

        # Iterate from 0 to end of the file, 
        # with increment = interval 
        for i in range(0, 2 * n, interval): 

            # During first iteration, 
            # start is 0, end is the interval 
            if i == 0: 
                start = 0
                end = interval 

            # All other iterations, 
            # start is the previous end - overlap 
            # end becomes end + interval 
            else: 
                start = end - overlap 
                end = start + interval  

            # When end becomes greater than the file length, 
            # end is set to the file length 
            # flag is set to 1 to indicate break. 
            if end >= n: 
                end = n 
                flag = 1

            # Storing audio file from the defined start to end 
            chunk = audio[start:end] 

            # Filename / Path to store the sliced audio 
            filename = str(chunk_count)+'chunk'+str(counter)+'.wav'

            # Store the sliced audio file to the defined path 
            chunk.export(filename, format ="wav") 
            # Print information about the current chunk 
            print(str(chunk_count)+str(counter)+". Start = "
                                +str(start)+" end = "+str(end)) 

            # Increment counter for the next chunk 
            counter = counter + 1


            AUDIO_FILE = filename 

            # Initialize the recognizer 
            r = sr.Recognizer() 

            # Traverse the audio file and listen to the audio 
            with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source: 
                audio_listened = r.listen(source) 

            # Try to recognize the listened audio 
            # And catch expections. 
            try:     
                rec = r.recognize_google(audio_listened) 

                # If recognized, write into the file. 
                fh.write(rec+" ") 

            # If google could not understand the audio 
            except sr.UnknownValueError: 
                    print("Empty Value") 

            # If the results cannot be requested from Google. 
            # Probably an internet connection error. 
            except sr.RequestError as e: 
                print("Could not request results.") 

            # Check for flag. 
            # If flag is 1, end of the whole audio reached. 
            # Close the file and break.                  
fh.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zach.blair\Downloads\speechRecognition\New folder\speechRecognition3.py", line 17, in 
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(filename,format="wav")
  File "C:\Users\zach.blair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 704, in from_file
    p.returncode, p_err))
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

b"ffmpeg version N-95027-g8c90bb8ebb Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers\r\n  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20190918\r\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf\r\n  libavutil      56. 35.100 / 56. 35.100\r\n  libavcodec     58. 58.101 / 58. 58.101\r\n  libavformat    58. 33.100 / 58. 33.100\r\n  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100\r\n  libavfilter     7. 58.102 /  7. 58.102\r\n  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100\r\n  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100\r\n  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100\r\nGuessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono\r\nInput #0, wav, from '2a.wav.wav':\r\n  Duration: 00:09:52.95, bitrate: 64 kb/s\r\n    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s\r\nStream mapping:\r\n  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_mulaw (native) -> pcm_s8 (native))\r\nPress [q] to stop, [?] for help\r\n[wav @ 0000024307974400] pcm_s8 codec not supported in WAVE format\r\nCould not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implemented\r\nError initializing output stream 0:0 -- \r\nConversion failed!\r\n"